# How to find identifier of a photo asset in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I am writing an app which saves a photo stored in a custom album and associates other information with it in an object. The object is then saved in core data. I would like to store a reference to the photo in the object. Is there a unique identifier that is available or can be derived. I need to be able to access the photo. I am using Photos framework.

Answer (score 2):

**Keep in mind that localIdentifier's may change when iOS is updated, and in this case whatever value you had saved locally will become useless.**

Check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094728/phobject-localidentifier-reliability/46819559#46819559) for further information.

Comment: localIdentifiers never changing on device. My app #pictagger is in appstore since 2015, no changes on localidentifier since then.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing from Photos framework is PHObject and the PHObject class implements the isEqual: and hash methods in terms of its localIdentifier property, you can use techniques that depend on these methods to keep track of photo entities.

```
var localIdentifier: String { get }
```

A unique string that persistently identifies the object

Comment: Thank you. I am still fuzzy. After I successfully save the photo, what returned property in the PHAsset is the identification of the photo?.

Comment: I interpret you question as"I can store array of localIdentifier in core data.How can i retrieve that photo later using localIdentifier stored in coredata ?" You can use fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers from PHAsset to Retrieve assets with the specified local-device-specific unique identifiers.

Comment: I need help to determine how to extract the identifier that needs to be stored in the localIdentifier. I am stuck at a basic level.

Comment: I think your idea on localIdentifier is wrong.you can get the value localIdentifier from PHObject and store that String value to your local DB and then use that local DB unique stored string to access the PHAsset you need by using methods.